# condition to determine between ceil and floor

Tags: php

how to create such condition in php, for example I have variable named $var (float). if $var greater than 0.3 then will be ceiled, else will be floored.
example:

```
if $var = 0.4 then $var = 1
if $var = 1.3 then $var = 1
if $var = 1.4 then $var = 2
if $var = 2.2 then $var = 2
if $var = 2.33 then $var = 3
```

Comment: Don't you mean to say "if *the decimal portion of* `$var` is greater than 0.3"?

Comment: I mean if $var smaller than 1 then return 1, else determine between ceil and floor.

Comment: The way you have worded your question, the code you provided notwithstanding, would mean ***any*** value of `$var` larger than 0.3 would be `ceil`'d.

Answer (score 2):

Shift it to a boundary condition and then use the function that moves it towards the other boundary. E.g., subtract 0.3 and ceil it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($var - intval($var) > 0.3){
    $var = intval($var) + 1;
}else{
    $var = intval($var);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple. Just use `%` php operator to check if division rest is greater then 0.3

```
if (($number - floor($number)) > 0.3)
{
    $number = ceil($number);
}
else
{
    $number = floor($number);
}
```

Comment: I didn't do that man. but I got 3.39 return 3 with your code.

Comment: Please try again with new code. I confused out with another languages.